# Not reaching aync callback, response hangs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I've run into an issue and I'm unsure what steps to take to fix it. Right now all the data is being correctly retrieved however the responseCallback is never firing and thus i'm not reaching the res.json call with the response array. Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

For clarification the problem is with the aysnc.each callback.

```
  var updatedBusinesses = [];
  googleplaces.radarSearch({location:"lat,long",radius:"10000",keyword:"keywordhere"},function(err,response){
   if(err){return next(err);}

   async.each(response.results,function(currResponse,responseCallback){
    Business.findOne({"placesId":currResponse.place_id,"claimed":true}).populate({path:'services',select:''}).exec(function(err,business){
     if(err){return next(err);}

     if(business !== null){
       Service.populate(business.services,{path:'employees',select:'_id appointments firstName lastName username avatarVersion'},function(err,newBusiness){
        if(err){return next(err);}

        googleplaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid:business.placesId},function(error,placesResult){
         if(error){return responseCallback(error);}

         console.log("RESULT OF THE GOOGLE PLACES DETAIL SEARCH")
         placesResult.result.info = business;
         updatedBusinesses.push(placesResult.result);
         // Here the data is populated and correct.
         // console.log(updatedBusinesses)
         responseCallback();

       });
     })
   }
 })
},function(err){
   if(err){return next(err);}
   console.log("called")
   res.json(updatedBusinesses);
 })
})
```

This is where I'm hoping to return the updated business information to the client however this never fires.

```
},function(err){
   if(err){return next(err);}
   console.log("called")
   res.json(updatedBusinesses);
 })
})
```

Comment: There are multiple callbacks here. Can you identify which one(s) are not firing?

Comment: Yes sorry, the async.each responseCallback

Comment: do you reach this ``` // console.log(updatedBusinesses)``` and if you uncomment it does it give you the right results?

Comment: yes the code reaches that statement & it does. it's exactly the data I would like to return to the client.

Comment: then your callback should be responseCallback(null, updatedBusinesses);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async.each() expects a callback (responseCallback) to be called for every iteration.  If it's not called, it's sitting there waiting for it.  That's why your update business section never gets called.

Inside your async.each(), there are a number of places calling next() which is not async.each()'s iteration's callback (responseCallback).  Here is the revised code that calls the callbacks properly:

```
var updatedBusinesses = [];

googleplaces.radarSearch({location:"lat,long",radius:"10000",keyword:"keywordhere"},function(err,response){
    if(err){return next(err);}

    async.each(response.results,function(currResponse,responseCallback){
        Business.findOne({"placesId":currResponse.place_id,"claimed":true}).populate({path:'services',select:''}).exec(function(err,business){
            if(err){
              return responseCallback(err);// <== calling responseCallback instead of next() 
            } 

            // in case of business === null/undefined, I'm not seeing any 
            // callback getting called, it needs to be called inside 
            // async.each() no matter which condition it is
            if (!business) {
               // call responseCallback to continue on with async.each()
                return responseCallback();
            }
            Service.populate(business.services,{path:'employees',select:'_id appointments firstName lastName username avatarVersion'},function(err,newBusiness){
                if(err){
                  return responseCallback(err);// <== calling responseCallback instead of next() 
                }

                googleplaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid:business.placesId},function(error,placesResult){
                    if(error){return responseCallback(error);}

                    console.log("RESULT OF THE GOOGLE PLACES DETAIL SEARCH")
                    placesResult.result.info = business;
                    updatedBusinesses.push(placesResult.result);
                    // Here the data is populated and correct.
                    // console.log(updatedBusinesses)
                    responseCallback();
                });
            })
        })
    },function(err){
        if(err){return next(err);}
        console.log("called");
        res.json(updatedBusinesses);
    });
});
```

So now responseCallback() is called for every condition inside async.each().  It should get down to "updated business information" part of the code now.

Comment: Thank you! That makes tons of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code `responseCallback();` with `responseCallback(null, [your-result]);` I think should do the job

```
var updatedBusinesses = []; googleplaces.radarSearch({location:"lat,long",radius:"10000",keyword:"keywordhere"},function(err,response){

if(err){return next(err);}

async.each(response.results,function(currResponse,responseCallback){    Business.findOne({"placesId":currResponse.place_id,"claimed":true}).populate({path:'services',select:''}).exec(function(err,business){
 if(err){return next(err);}

 if(business !== null){
   Service.populate(business.services,{path:'employees',select:'_id appointments firstName lastName username avatarVersion'},function(err,newBusiness){
    if(err){return next(err);}

    googleplaces.placeDetailsRequest({placeid:business.placesId},function(error,placesResult){
     if(error){return responseCallback(error);}

     console.log("RESULT OF THE GOOGLE PLACES DETAIL SEARCH")
     placesResult.result.info = business;
     updatedBusinesses.push(placesResult.result);
     // Here the data is populated and correct.
     // console.log(updatedBusinesses)
     responseCallback(null, updatedBusinesses);

   });
 })
} }) },function(err, updatedBusinesses){
   if(err){return next(err);}
   console.log("called")
   res.json(updatedBusinesses);
 })
})
```

Comment: Thanks bianca, however I have tried this solution and it does not work. Based on the Async library docs located here: https://github.com/caolan/async#each   I don't think i can pass a second argument to that callback. When i try this method no data is passed.. meaning the updatedBusinesses array doesn't get passed into the callback. The response still hangs.